# Using a VSS Control on a TFS Dashboard Widget

Tags: javascript, tfs, widget, azure-devops

I am attempting to add a Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) [Multivalue Combo Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/ui-controls/comboo?view=vsts) in a custom tfs dashboard widget's configuration page. I am able to get the widget to appear and I can dynamically add values to it. But I am unable to "Save" the value. Below is the Javascript I am using to attempt to create and save this control's values. I recieve the error from the browsers console of "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'notify' of undefined" from line 34 (my "change" function inside my multiselect. I have attenpted to put the logic inside of the "load" function as that is genrally where you put the logic for the widget, but then i receive a error specifying that "create" is undefined in my `var multiValueCombo = Controls.create(Combos.Combo, CustomContainer, multiValueOptions);` line.

With how the current code stands. The "save button" does not enable when I make a change to the value in my control. I believe this is due to the "notify" function not firing.

```
VSS.require(["TFS/Dashboards/WidgetHelpers", "TFS/DistributedTask/TaskAgentRestClient", "VSS/Controls", "VSS/Controls/Combos"], function (WidgetHelpers, TFS_TaskAgentRestClient, Controls, Combos) {
VSS.register("DeploymentReports.Configuration", function () {
    var CustomContainer = $("#custom-combo-container");

    //Creating the Multiselect Control
    var multiValueOptions = {
        type: "multi-value",
        width: 250,
        source: [
            "Ford"],
        change: function () {
            //What it does when you change the value of the multiselect

            var customSettings = { data: JSON.stringify({ iteration: this.getText() }) };
            var eventName = WidgetHelpers.WidgetEvent.ConfigurationChange;
            var eventArgs = WidgetHelpers.WidgetEvent.Args(customSettings);
            widgetConfigurationContext.notify(eventName, eventArgs);   //I get an error for this line "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'notify' of undefined"
        }
    }
    $("<label />").text("Select the supported languages:").appendTo(CustomContainer);

    var multiValueCombo = Controls.create(Combos.Combo, CustomContainer, multiValueOptions);

    var commandArea = $("<div style='margin:auto' />").appendTo(CustomContainer);


    return {
        load: function (widgetSettings, widgetConfigurationContext, Controls, Combos) { 

            //adding items to the multiselect drop down
            multiValueOptions.source.push("Volvo");
            multiValueOptions.source.push("Jeep");
            return WidgetHelpers.WidgetStatusHelper.Success();
        },

        //Clicking the Save Button
        onSave: function() {
            var customSettings = {
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    cars: multiValueOptions.getText()
                    })
            };                              
            return WidgetHelpers.WidgetConfigurationSave.Valid(customSettings); 
        }
    }
});
VSS.notifyLoadSucceeded();
```

});

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, seems you want to save the data in the combo control. VSTS extensions have the ability to store user preferences and complex data structures directly on Microsoft-provided infrastructure.

There are two ways to interact with the data storage service: REST APIs or a Microsoft-provided client service available as part of the VSS SDK. It is highly recommended that extension developers use the provided client service APIs, which provide a convenient wrapper over the REST APIs.

Take a look a the concept about **[Data storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/data-storage?view=vsts)**.  This ensures your user's data is secure and backed up just like other account and project data. It also means for simple data storage needs, you (as the extension provider) are not required to setup or manage (or pay for) third-party data storage services.

> The service is designed to let you store and manage two different
>   types of data:
>
> - Settings: simple key-value settings (like user preferences)
> - Documents: collections of similar complex objects (documents)

More details about how to set storage please refer official [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/data-storage?view=vsts#setting-storage).